# Rails Basic Question about Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, devise

in devise, the forms look like this:

```
form_for(:resource, @resource, :url => edit_user(resource), :html => {:method=> put}) do |f|
```

but I'm wondering, does it have to include method => put? Isn't REST supposed to have taken care of that already?

I've tried using form_for(@resource) but it does not get the edit user path. I think I am missing something here. Any help will be very much helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of there rails guides [talks about this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-put-or-delete-methods-work), here is a snippet:

> The Rails framework encourages RESTful design of your applications,
>   which means you’ll be making a lot of “PUT” and “DELETE” requests
>   (besides “GET” and “POST”). However, most browsers don’t support
>   methods other than “GET” and “POST” when it comes to submitting forms.
>
> Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over POST
>   with a hidden input named “_method”, which is set to reflect the
>   desired method...

You populate this hidden input using `:html => {:method=> put}` this gives rails a bit of hint. Using this hint and the url you're submitting to rails can work out which of the restful action to submit the form to.

Have a read of that rails guide that I linked to, things should become a lot clearer after that.